# monodroid activity - wrong activity at start up

Tags: xamarin.android

I have developed a monodroid application with several activities.

Occasionally, the wrong activity is shown first, as opposed to the one with "MainLauncher=true" set.

Also, occasionally I get a dialog stating "Could not determine activity to run because the generated manifest could not be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I occasionally see the wrong activity on startup.

I think this generally seems to be when I haven't changed any code and try to restart my application for a second debugging session.

I think what happens in this case, it that Android tries to restart my application on the page/Activity where I last left it. This situation also happens when the app is in general use - so it's good practice to write your code so that the app works in this situation (e.g. using the saved instance state bundle)